# What does Failed_Reason_Other_Than_A_Connection_Already_Exists mean?

Tags: rfid, llrp

I am trying to connect to a Impinj Speedway RFID reader using LLRP and I am getting the following error code: Failed_Reason_Other_Than_A_Connection_Already_Exists

More specifically I am sending a GET_READER_CONFIG message and getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<llrp:READER_EVENT_NOTIFICATION xmlns:llrp="http://www.llrp.org/ltk/schema/core/encoding/xml/1.0" Version="1" MessageID="0">
    <llrp:ReaderEventNotificationData>
        <llrp:UTCTimestamp>
            <llrp:Microseconds>50408-10-10T04:34:25.209Z</llrp:Microseconds>
        </llrp:UTCTimestamp>
        <llrp:ConnectionAttemptEvent>   
            <llrp:Status>Failed_Reason_Other_Than_A_Connection_Already_Exists</llrp:Status>
        </llrp:ConnectionAttemptEvent>
    </llrp:ReaderEventNotificationData>
</llrp:READER_EVENT_NOTIFICATION>
```

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I solved the problem.

In my case the reason was that the region of the Speedway was not set and then the RFID was disabled.

To set the region, I had to log in using SSH and then run the following command:

```
config system region 13
```

Where 13 is my region. To see your region, use the following commands:

```
show
system
? region
```

Comment: Thank you! When typing the command >show system region, you get a list of available regions for that reader

Comment: In my case, a reboot was necessary after the `config system region 13`. Thanks.